# Is there a funtion in PineScript for calculating the number of bars lasting for the next Upper timeframe resolution bar?

Tags: pine-script, resolution

I'm coding a new pinescript strategy in tradingview. I have 2 resolution timeframes: Upper Time Frame is 4 Days and lower is 65 minutes.

Based on the 65 minutes timeframe (6 candles per day, 24 candles for each 4D candle), is there any way to calculate the number of 65minutes candles lasting for the next 4 days resolution candle?

```
//@version=3
study("SinceyNew")
res = "4D"
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
plot(is_newbar(res))
color=na
if is_newbar(res)>0
    color := black
bgcolor(color)
plot(24-barssince(is_newbar(res)))
```

Thanks In Advance!

I've this code that tells me the number of bars, the problem that i'm experiencing is that some 4Days bars are not composed by 24 bars of 65 minutes (because of hollydays, etc)

Comment: If you're asking about precise amount of bars, then, no, you can't get any information about how many bars there will be in the next period. Because there can be a situation, when no one has bought the security in the next N periods, so any bars will created. Such situation happens with unpopular shares or with futures contracts, before the became active traded etc.

Comment: sorry, I marked the wrong thread as duplicate - not intentional.